# Join the splitted string again skipping one index of the array formed from splitting

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, url

I am working on this url:
**demo.example.in/posts/0ewsd/13213**

And I need to get the hostname (**demo.example.in**) from this URL followed by the path (**posts/0ewsd/13213**)

`urlHost = 'demo.example.in/posts/0ewsd/13213';
let urlHostName = urlHost.split("/");`

I tried using **split()** method, but it ended up splitting the whole URL...
`['demo.example.in', 'posts', '0ewsd', '13213']`

What I need is to get **demo.example.in** and **posts/0ewsd/13213**
Is there any way out for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with the next regular expression `/^([^/]*)\/(.*)$/` using capturing groups:

```js
const url = "demo.example.in/posts/0ewsd/13213";

const customSplit = (url) =>
{
    let matches = url.match(/^([^/]*)\/(.*)$/);
    return [matches[1], matches[2]];
}

let [hostname, path] = customSplit(url);

console.log("hostname => " + hostname);
console.log("path => " + path);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Alternatively, with [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) you can do next:

```js
const url = "demo.example.in/posts/0ewsd/13213";

const customSplit = (url) =>
{
    let [hostname, ...path] = url.split("/");
    return [hostname, path.join("/")];
}

let [hostname, path] = customSplit(url);

console.log("hostname => " + hostname);
console.log("path => " + path);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: This was the thing I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression if you want - match and capture anything but a `/` (hostname), then match a `/`, then match and capture the rest of the line (path). The hostname will be in the first captured group, and the path will be in the second captured group:

```js
const input = 'demo.example.in/posts/0ewsd/13213';
const [, hostname, path] = input.match(/([^/]+)\/(.*)/);
console.log(hostname, path);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and some addition to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

```
var urlHost = 'demo.example.in/posts/0ewsd/13213';

const [host, param] = [urlHost.substring(0, urlHost.indexOf('/')), urlHost.substring(urlHost.indexOf('/') + 1)];

console.log(host, param);
```

Hope this helps you !

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solve this by using regular Expression grouping feature. Below regEx will group the string in 3 groups.First will the host then the delimiter(/) and then the path.

```
var patt = /^([\w\.]*)(\/)(.*)$/gim;
```

[Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2JJ4L4HOXDD)

Answer (score 0):

If you can prefix the scheme to the url, you can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) API to get host and path.

```js
const url = new URL('http://' + 'demo.example.in/posts/0ewsd/13213');
const host = url.host, path = url.pathname.slice(1);

console.log('Host:', host);
console.log('URL Path:', path);
```